# Can't write image data to path from my admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, image, file-upload, intervention

So I have this code for uploading images in my laravel app:

```
 $imageName = rand(111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
 $imagePath = 'images/category_images/' . $imageName;

 Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(533, 533)->save($imagePath);
```

It works perfectly on localhost, but after deploying the code online, I can't read or write images from the admin panel of my app. It works on the user part though (The user part can read images).

I've set the permissions on the folders to 775 and on files to 644. So I really have no idea why this isn't working. Please help

This is the error I get when I try to upload:

Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException

Can't write image data to path (images/category_images/74327.png)

Comment: Are there any error displayed on the page? logs?

Comment: Does the saving fail or the resizing? Might be a missing PHP image extension.

Comment: @brombeer The saving fails, I get an error saying I can't write image data to path, so I figured it was a permissions issue, but the permissions are fine

Comment: @Mr Kenneth, yeah there was an error on the page saying I can't write image data to path

Comment: Please post the _complete_ error message in your question

Comment: Post the error in the question and also where the error was from (page, logs, which logs, etc)

Comment: @brombeer, done that

Comment: Try using the complete path, like `/var/www/html/images/category_images/`

Comment: I guess it is trying to upload the image on the same folder as the controller. Try to change `$imagePath = 'images/category_images/' . $imageName;` to `$imagePath = storage_path('app/public') . 'images/category_images/' . $imageName;` where it will be stored in `root/storage/app/public/images/○○`

Comment: you might need to run `php artisan storage:link` to create symlink for your storage and public folder

Comment: @Mr. Kenneth, still didn't work, same error "Can't write image data to path"

Comment: @brombeer still didn't work, same error "Can't write image data to path"

Comment: Okay let me try creating the symlink @Mr. Kenneth

Comment: Instead of `Image` Facade, try to use the `Storage` Facade instead. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth okay I'll check it out. But out of curiosity, why do you think the Image Intervention package isn't working. This is the first time I've had this issue since using it, that's why I'm so confused

Comment: Not sure. I mainly use Storage facade when moving files in laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it with public_path($path)

```
$imagePath = public_path('images/category_images/' . $imageName);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't specify where you want to store your image as I can see you try to store it in the /image folder or it's not recommended and I think you don't have a permission to write there.
So if you want to store in the public folder public/image:
`$imagePath ='images/category_images/'.$imageName;`
as mentioned in the first answer or if you want to store in the storage path add storage_path('path') and if you do this do forget to link the storage path by executing the command

> php artisan storage:link